# Better approach to display multiple category in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am working in one website ,there i have to show multiple category information in home page.Presently my code look like below in controller

```
public function category1()
{
    //here 1 is category id
    $category1 = POST::find(1);
    return view('books.index',compact('category1'));
}
public function category2()
{
    //here 2 is category id
    $category2 = POST::find(3);
    return view('books.index',compact('category2'));
}
public function category3()
{
    //here 3 is category id
    $category3 = POST::find(3);
    return view('books.index',compact('category3'));
}
```

and in my view i am displaying each category data.but i think this will make site slow because in home i am going to display around 15 category .for each category i am creating methods.i hope it is not a better approach.Please suggest me better approach so i can use single method.

thank you in advance

**Updated question** ::

my route looke like

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

and mysql table look like

```
id|post_title|post_content|cat_id
```

in my home page i have 15 boxes which have 15 category information.now i am calling each request to each category.my question is can i do that in single request when i navigate to my home url like www.myurl.com

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to exactly understand your problem, but what about:

```
public function category($categoryId)
{
    $category = POST::find($categoryId);
    return view('books.index',compact('category'));
}
```

And if needed, in your routes.php file:

```
Route::get('/category/{id}', 'MyController@category');
```

Update:

If you are trying to display several pieces of code in the same page, you should do something like :

```
public function category()
{
    $category1 = POST::find(1);
    $category2 = POST::find(2);
    $category3 = POST::find(3);
    return view('books.index',compact('category1', 'category2', 'category3'));
}
```

Update 2:

What I would do:

```
public function getCategories(){
    $categoryModel = new CategoryModel;
    $categories = $categoryModel->getAllCategories();
    return view('books.index', compact('categories');
}
```

And a model could be:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class CategoryModel extends Model {

    function getAllCategories(){

        $categories = DB::table('categories')
                 ->get();

        return $categories;
    }
}
```

Comment: @vico.thank you for the answer but my route url like Route::get('/', 'MyController@category'); means www.myurl.com  for example website like eebhoomi.com

Comment: I'm still not really sure to understand, but I've updated my post with another solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: ,your update answer is ok. if you can visit www.eebhoomi.com there they have many category in home page .same way i am working

Comment: To be honest, the best way is to have a function (Model) in charge of getting all the categories. Then you send the categories to your view (books.index) and this view deals with the category display.

Comment: Updated again. But I highly suggest you to read the docs first (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/) and watch some podcasts (https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals)